# Sorting Data using LINQ.Dynamic

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I want to populate a table using JSON data. This works perfectly.
However the issue occurs when I want to view the data. I keep on running into 
'No property or field 'RegistrationIDasc' exists in type 'UserModel'.
My UserModel contains the string RegistrationID.I don't understand the addtional "asc".
This is the controller

```
    public ActionResult LoadRolesData()
    {
        try
        {
            var draw = Request.Form.GetValues("draw").FirstOrDefault();
            var start = Request.Form.GetValues("start").FirstOrDefault();
            var length = Request.Form.GetValues("length").FirstOrDefault();
            var sortColumn = Request.Form.GetValues("columns[" + Request.Form.GetValues("order[0][column]").FirstOrDefault() + "][name]").FirstOrDefault();
            var sortColumnDir = Request.Form.GetValues("order[0][dir]").FirstOrDefault();
            var searchValue = Request.Form.GetValues("search[value]").FirstOrDefault();
            int pageSize = length != null ? Convert.ToInt32(length) : 0;
            int skip = start != null ? Convert.ToInt32(start) : 0;

            int recordsTotal = 0;

            var rolesData = _IAssignRoles.ShowallRoles(sortColumn, sortColumnDir, searchValue);
            recordsTotal = rolesData.Count();


            return Json(new { draw, recordsFiltered = recordsTotal, recordsTotal });
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw; //exception thrown here
        }
    }
```

Below is the class model

```
            public IQueryable<UserModel> ShowallRoles(string sortColumn, string sortColumnDir, string Search)
    {
        var result = (from AssignedRoles in db.AssignedRoles
                         join registration in db.Registration on AssignedRoles.RegistrationID equals registration.RegistrationID
                         join AssignedRolesAdmin in db.Registration on AssignedRoles.AssignToAdmin equals AssignedRolesAdmin.RegistrationID
                         select new UserModel
                         {
                             Name = registration.Name,
                             AssignToAdmin = string.IsNullOrEmpty(AssignedRolesAdmin.Name) ? "*Not Assigned*" : AssignedRolesAdmin.Name.ToUpper(),
                             RegistrationID = registration.RegistrationID
                         });
        if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortColumn) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortColumnDir))) //first exception thrown
        {
            result = result.Where(sortColumn + "" + sortColumnDir);
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Search))
        {
            result = result.Where(m => m.Name == Search);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: `result = result.Where(sortColumn + "" + sortColumnDir);` should probably be result = `result.Orderby(sortColumn + " " + sortColumnDir);` but still that wont work... so you will need a switch to decide if its "orderby" or "orderbydescneding". and change depending on that. it should also be after the search if block

Comment: @Seabizkit 's approach would be better and more readable

Answer (score 1):

Pseudo code

```
public IQueryable<UserModel> ShowallRoles(string sortColumn, string sortColumnDir, string Search)
{
    var result = (from AssignedRoles in db.AssignedRoles
                 join registration in db.Registration on AssignedRoles.RegistrationID equals registration.RegistrationID
                 join AssignedRolesAdmin in db.Registration on AssignedRoles.AssignToAdmin equals AssignedRolesAdmin.RegistrationID
                 select new UserModel
                 {
                     Name = registration.Name,
                     AssignToAdmin = string.IsNullOrEmpty(AssignedRolesAdmin.Name) ? "*Not Assigned*" : AssignedRolesAdmin.Name.ToUpper(),
                     RegistrationID = registration.RegistrationID
                 });
    
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Search))
    {
        result = result.Where(m => m.Name == Search);
    }       
    
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortColumn))
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortColumnDir))
        {
            if(sortColumnDir == "asc")
                result = result.OrderBy(sortColumn);
            else
                result = result.OrderByDescending(sortColumn);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: beat me by a second :D :D